# How should i make DetailView in Django, gives 404

Tags: django, django-views

in file "views.py" i added next code:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = "news/details_view.html"
    context_object_name = 'article'
```

then in the file urls.py I added to urlpatterns next:

```
path('<int:pk>', views.NewsDetailView.as_view(), name="news_detail"),
```

and created the template "details_view.html".
When i write to browser:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1

it gives 404 error
[404 error in DetailView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQOFc.png)

Comment: Looks like you don't have an article with 1 pk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Admin Site](https://%20http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/) and add at least one `Articles` object.

Alternatively, you can create it in shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from yourapp.models import Articles
>>> Articles.objects.create(...)
```